# download specific version of serenity-cli jar in package.json protractor project

Tags: serenity-bdd, serenity-js

Is there a way I can download specific version of serenity-cli jar.

senario: I want to use the specific version of old jar of cli, where do I mention the version of the jar in the package.json .

TIA

Answer (score 0):

To see the command line options of `serenity-bdd update` command run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/serenity-bdd --help update
```

To use a specific version of the jar, run:

```
serenity-bdd update --artifact net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cli:jar:all:2.1.12
```